# Meteor-aldded:tabular collection undefined error

Tags: meteor, tabular

I have the following table which works ok. Beeing an admin account I published the whole Meteor.users collection. I also have two databases in a file in the root /lib

```
Clients = new Meteor.Collection("client");
Brands = new Meteor.Collection("brand");
```

They are published for now like this in the /server/lib folder

```
Meteor.publish("pubClients", function(){
  return Clients.find();
});
Meteor.publish("pubBrands", function(){
  return Brands.find();
});
Meteor.publish("pubUsers", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

And subscribed like this in the client/lib folder

```
Meteor.subscribe('pubClients');
Meteor.subscribe('pubBrands');
Meteor.subscribe('pubUsers');
```

I am using the following template to inject the html:
{{> tabular table=TabularTables.Users selector=selector class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}

Now if I try to change the Meteor.user to any of the Clients or Brands collection or even inserting above this code a console.log(Clients) I get a: "Clients is not defined" error.
If I type in the console > Clients before running rerunning the app it works fine with Mongo.Collection etc.
If I run it I get the undefined message in the console too.
This is my code ( in fact aldeed's code :) ):

```
TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Users = new Tabular.Table({
name: "UserList",
collection: Meteor.users,
pub:"pubUsers"
columns: [
{data: "username", title: "User name"},
{
  data: "emails",
  title: "Email",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return val[0].main
  }
},
{
  data: "emails",
  title: "verified",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return val[0].verified?"☑":"☐";
  }
},
{
data: "profile",
title: "Account",
render: function (val, type, doc) {
return val.accType;
}
},
{
  data: "profile",
  title: "Active",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return val.active?"active":"pending";
  }
},
{
  data: "createdAt",
  title: "Singned up",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return moment(val).calendar();
  }
},
  {
    tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.bookCheckOutCell
  }
]
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.This is my package list:

> ```
> accounts-base      1.1.3  A user account system
>
> accounts-password  1.0.5  Password support for accounts
>
> aldeed:tabular     0.2.3  Datatables for large or small datasets in Meteor
>
> insecure           1.0.2  Allow all database writes by default
>
> iron:router        1.0.6  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
>
> meteor-platform    1.2.1  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
>
> momentjs:moment    2.9.0  Moment.js (official): parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates - official Meteor packaging
>
> sergeyt:typeahead  0.10.5_7  Autocomplete package for meteor powered by twitter typeahead.js
>
> twbs:bootstrap     3.3.1_2  Bootstrap (official): the most popular HTML/CSS/JS framework for responsive, mobile first projects
> ```

I am using this collection in other points of the app and it works fine. Since I installed the tabular package
things got out of hand somehow. I don't have the slights idea were to start from.
I am struggling now for two days to get it working, but there's so few information on the web about this package (and most Meteor related subjects) that I decided to post this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, looks like load order issue

Try writing the tabular code after the initialization of collections in the same file like

in root/lib folder

```
Clients = new Meteor.Collection("client");
Brands = new Meteor.Collection("brand");


Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

    TabularTables.Users = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "UserList",
    collection: Meteor.users, //Clientsor Brands
    pub:"pubUsers"
    columns: [
    {data: "username", title: "User name"},
    {
      data: "emails",
      title: "Email",
      render: function (val, type, doc) {
        return val[0].main
      }
    },
```

Comment: You made my day!!!! If on top of up-voting there would be a button "Hugs" I would push it too. I realise now load order is crucial. Can you please recommend me a doc or something to learn how i can control this. A package.js maybe? ()I pretty new to meteor and I don't "feel" the framework yet. Thanks again a thousand times!

Comment: @vladblindu, to know file load order visit this link http://www.meteorsnippets.com/blog/files-load-order-in-meteor